# create common function in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two list

```
men=['x','y','z']
women=['a','b','c'];
```

and two vabriable to show in html

```
selectedMan;
selectedWoman;
```

i want to create a common select method

```
select(index,source,destination){
  destination=source[index];
}
```

function call

```
this.select(2,this.men,this.selectedMan);
this.select(1,this.women,this.selectedWoman)
```

html

```
<p>Welcome to team {{selectedMan}}</p>
<p>Welcome to team {{selectedWoman}}</p>
```

but in html only show welcome to team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a common function do it the right way.Learn the difference between pass by value and pass by reference. [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373419/5695162)

**Solution**

Method definition

```
select(index,source){
 return source[index];
}
```

method call

```
 this.selectedMan=this.select(2,this.men)
 this.selectedWoman=this.select(1,this.women);
```

Answer (score 2):

Arguments are passed by value, not by reference. All your function does is to change the value of the local variable `destination`. So it actually does nothing.

Frankly, I don't see the point. Even if it worked,

```
this.select(1,this.women,this.selectedWoman)
```

is longer, and less clear than

```
this.selectedWoman = this.women[1];
```

If you really wanted such a function, you would need, for example

```
select(index: number, array: Array<string>, callback: (s: string) => void) {
  callback(array[index]);
}
```

and use it this way:

```
this.select(1, this.men, s => this.selectedMan = s);
```

Or (but this is less safe, and doesn't allow for minification):

```
select(index: number, array: Array<string>, property: string) {
  this[property] = array[index]);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
this.select(1, this.men, 'selectedMan');
```

Comment: tnx for feeback.acullay it is a demo problem,i want to use common function to compact my my project.

Comment: How can i pass by reference?

Comment: You can't. maybe if you explained what you really want to achieve, with an example that makes more sense, we could help.